# Two people picking balls from an infinite set both seem the have the advantage?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Here is the problem that I'm trying to figure out.

There is an unlimited pile of balls. They are numbered by 1, 2, 3, . . ..
Two players A and B randomly select one ball each and check their number. The
winner is the player who picked the lowest numbered ball. Let us consider the
chances of winning of player A. Assume that player A picked a ball with number k.
As there is a finite number of balls numbered lower than k and unlimited number
of balls with larger numbers, then we can conclude that the chance of player A
winning is much more likely than loosing. However, the same argument works for
the player B. Thus, both players have advantage over the other player. How is it
possible?

Lets say that Player A picks the ball first and gets an arbitrary number "k". Then the only chance that he has of losing is if Player B draws a ball between $1,...,k-1$. Let "n" denote the number of balls. Then the chance of player A winning seems to be

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}=\frac{n-(k-1)}{n}=1$$

In this scenario it seems like Player A is pretty much guaranteed victory, but if you look at it from the perspective of Player B. Then by similar reasoning he would also seem to be guaranteed victory after selecting his ball. I'm really confused on how to resolve this problem because it doesn't make sense both players having an advantage yet in this problem it seems like they do.

Comment: There is no uniform probability distribution on the natural numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "uniform probability distribution"?

Comment: In other words, you just can't randomly select one ball from an unlimited pile.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why not?

Comment: Well, what probability is there of picking any ball? If it is $p$, then $\sum_n p = \infty$ for any $p \neq 0$. This means that if the $p$s are all the same, $p=0$, which won't work. The distribution has to be weighted in some way, which then resolves the issue.

Comment: Its an infinite set so there doesn't seem to be any fixed probability.

Comment: The probability to pick any particular ball is zero - but that doesn't mean it won't happen. E.g. pick a real number between 0 and 1: zero probability for any specific number, but you can still pick one.

Comment: @TomCollinge : no, as probability is countably additive, the probability to pick any particular ball **cannot** be 0, or else the probability to pick a ball would be 0 too. It works with reals because they are not countable

Comment: @Tryss So, my unlimited pile of balls isn't countable either. On the other hand, pick a rational number between 0 and 1.

Comment: @TomCollinge wouldn't the unlimited pile of balls be countable since the cardinality of the set of all balls would be the same all the set of all natural numbers and the set of all natural numbers is countable.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish Do you minded explaining what you mean by "the distribution has to be weighted in some way". I actually haven't worked with probability distributions before so I was wondering if you could give me a concrete example of what a weighted probability distribution would be?

Comment: @user262291 It depends how many there are doesn't it ! Let's do a quick reality check here: there is no such thing as an "unlimited" pile of balls, so if we are going to hypothesize about such we can make it countably infinite or we could make it uncountably infinite, perhaps of the same cardinality as the real numbers. The fact that you could start creating a surjection onto  the natural numbers (i.e.  counting them) doesn't mean it would be a bijection when finished.

Comment: To make sense of picking one ball at random from an infinite pile, you need to specify the probability of picking each ball; those probabilities must sum to one. An example would be to pick ball $k$ with probability $1/2^k$, since these probabilities do sum to $1$. But the probabilities can't be the same for all the balls, since the sum would not be finite.

Comment: @TomCollinge: You **cannot** pick a rational number between $0$ and $1$ uniformly. If you disagree, give an **explicit** probability distribution.